# Javascript not interrupting CSS Animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, timer

I am trying to use JavaScript to interrupt a CSS animation that fades a DIV element. The fading text via CSS works just fine, however, the timed JavaScript function does not "interrupt" the fade at the set interval. I have been scratching my head on this for awhile now and am wondering if certain CSS animations cannot be interrupted/cancelled by JavaScript. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

```
<style type="text/css">
#fadeMe {
    opacity:1.0;
    animation:fadeEffect 6s infinite;
    -webkit-animation:fadeEffect 6s infinite; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

@keyframes fadeEffect
{
    from { opacity: 1.0; }
    to { opacity: 0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeEffect /* Safari and Chrome */
{
    from { opacity: 1.0; }
    to { opacity: 0; }
}
</style>
<div id="fadeMe">
    <p> Fade this text </p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function(){interruptFade()},3000);
    function interruptFade() {
        var div = document.getElementById('fadeMe');
        div.style.opacity = "1.0";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval(function(){
        interruptFade();},3000);
    function interruptFade() {
        var div = document.getElementById('fadeMe');
        div.style.opacity += 0.1;
    }`

Comment: I gave that a try but still no luck. I've done some digging around on the internet and it seems that other animations were "interruptible" via Javascript (e.g., using a button to prevent a div element from sliding). However, for some reason, opacity seems to be a different issue.

Comment: if you are using jquery you can try using fadeOut() and fadeIn()

Comment: I'll look into that option. Based on a suggestion from another user, was trying to use CSS animations to constantly be working to fade-out the div elements while JavaScript works to keep the elements *not* fading out ... all so that we prevent the user (students) from disabling JavaScript during exams. (Just so you had context on why this option is even being explored).

Answer (score 0):

You could just pause the animation.

```
setInterval(interruptFade, 3000);


function interruptFade() {
    var fade = document.getElementById("fadeMe");
    fade.style.webkitAnimationPlayState = 'paused';
}
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/39tv7/4/

You can use:

```
var fade = document.getElementById("fadeMe");
fade.style.webkitAnimationPlayState = 'running';
```

if you want to resume the animation.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the CSS animation to continue running at all times. We are trying to prevent students from disabling JS during exams since our JS detects printscreen keys being pressed. A suggestion was made to have the CSS animation constantly working to "hide" the content while our JS fights to keep it visible. If the user turns off JS, the CSS wins out and they have nothing to printscreen.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using CSS `transition` instead of `animation`?

http://jsfiddle.net/PW75k/

Not sure how you are trying to apply the desired effect, but in the example I am applying a class with the transition then setting the opacity to the current opacity at the time of interrupt and then removing the transition class.

Comment: We are trying to prevent students from disabling JS during exams since our JS detects printscreen keys being pressed. A suggestion was made to have the CSS animation constantly working to "hide" the content while our JS fights to keep it visible. If the user turns off JS, the CSS wins out and they have nothing to printscreen.